# Virtual Host Redirects to Default

Tags: subdomain, apache-http-server

I am running Debian and Apache.

I wish to create a new dev environment on my dev server. Let's call it dev2. Currently the dev server is only hosting dev. My production server is hosting the live site, accessible via `*.example.com`. After following the steps below to set up `dev2.example.com` with it's own docroot, the URL for dev2 is forwarding to `dev.example.com`, the default site on the dev server.

Here are the steps I took:

- In our hosting account, we have an A record for `www` to go to the
  production server's IP. Another A record for `dev.example.com` goes to
  the dev server and that URL loads the default dev website. I created
  a new A record for `dev2` also pointing to the IP address of the dev
  server.
- I pinged `dev2.example.com` to make sure it worked and there was no packet loss.
- I created a new docroot and a dummy index: `/var/www/html/dev2/docroot/index.html`
- Next, I created a `dev2.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and
  created a symlink to it from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.
- Then I ran the command `sudo a2ensite dev2.conf` and reloaded apache
  via `service apache2 reload`. Lastly, I cleared the cache of the
  browser and when that didn't work, I restarted apache2.

What am I missing? Here are the contents of the `dev2.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
        ServerAdmin tech@example.com
        ServerSignature email
        ServerName dev2.example.com
        DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev2/docroot
        HostNameLookups off
        RewriteEngine on

        # Force SSL
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev2\.example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dev2.example.com$1 [L,R=301]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dev2.example.com$1 [L,R=301]

        # Force our domain name
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^dev2\.example\.com [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://dev2.example.com/$1 [L,R]

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/dev2/docroot>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted

                # For friendly URLs
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:** I also tried adding the line `ServerAlias dev2.example.com` under ServerName to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the actual domain that you are asking about
(now redacted, represented by `example.com`),
you have a bit of a mess in your current configurations:

> wget http://**dev**.example.com
>   --2017-03-14 22:20:03--  `http://dev.example.com/`
>   Resolving dev.example.com... 206.123.xxx.182
>   Connecting to dev.example.com|206.123.xxx.182|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... **301 Moved Permanently**
>   Location: http**s**://**dev2**.example.com/ [following]

For some reason the plain http site on `dev` redirects to the https site for `dev2`. Permanent redirects (301 responses) are cached by most web browsers, so please be careful when testing each and every configuration change you apply. Either test with command line tools or use a new private browser window for each test...

> wget http://**dev2**.example.com
>   **URL transformed to HTTPS** due to an HSTS policy
>   --2017-03-14 22:24:45--  `https://dev2.example.com/`
>   Resolving dev2.example.com... 206.123.xxx.182
>   Connecting to dev2.example.com|206.123.xxx.182|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... **302 Found**
>   Location: http**s**://**dev**.example.com/ [following]

The `dev2` site does something different from `dev`; an HSTS policy gets applied to redirect to HTTPS and then a redirect (a temporary 302 redirect in this case) to `dev` happens.

In summary: `dev` is redirecting to `dev2`
and `dev2` is redirecting to `dev`.

You need to check not only the config for `dev2` but also the config for `dev` on both the plain http virtual host on port 80 as well as the SSL virtual host config on port 443.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I was creating a symlink in sites-enabled to /etc/apache2/sites-available/dev2.conf I had put in a typo so that it was redirecting to sites-available/dev.conf. Regards.